# Find duplicates in one column and return indices of both duplicates

Tags: python, indexing, duplicates

Complete newbie here so please bear with me (including how to enter code into this!).

I want to identify if there are any duplicate ages.  If there is, then I want to see the names (or indices) of the two (or more) that have the same age.  If there are two different sets of duplicates, e.g. two aged 3 and two aged 5, I then want to identify the oldest pair (age 5).

In the instance below, I want it to read `Felix` and `Alex`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

name = ("Bob", "Stu", "Felix", "Rupert", "Alex")
age = [random.randint(1, 5) for i in range(len(name))]
job = ("Paramedic", "Police Officer", "Fireman", "Coastguard", "Astronaut")

for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i] + "\t" + str(age[i]) + "\t" + job[i])

oldest_kid = name[0]
oldest = age[0]

for i in range(len(name)):
    if oldest < age[i]:
        oldest_kid = name[i]
        oldest = age[i]

print("\n" + oldest_kid)
```

Output:

```
Bob     3    Paramedic
Stu     1    Police Officer
Felix   5    Fireman
Rupert  3    Coastguard
Alex    5    Astronaut

Felix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a solution using your code. There must be more effective methods, but this has the advantage of being easier to understand for a beginner.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

name = ("Bob", "Stu", "Felix", "Rupert", "Alex")
age = [random.randint(1, 5) for i in range(len(name))]
job = ("Paramedic", "Police Officer", "Fireman", "Coastguard", "Astronaut")

for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i] + "\t" + str(age[i]) + "\t" + job[i])

oldest_kid = name[0]
oldest = age[0]

ageList = [0] * 5 # 5 different age

for i in range(len(name)):
    ageList[ age[i] - 1 ] += 1

# find group of people with the same age
for i in range(len(ageList)):
    if ageList[i] >= 2: # 2 or more people have the same age
        groupe=""
        for j in range(len(name)):
            if age[j] == i+1:
                groupe += name[j]+" "
        if groupe != "":
            print("Groupe : " + groupe)

# find oldest groupe of peopple with the same age
for i in range(4,-1,-1): # start by the older
    if ageList[i] >= 2:
        groupe=""
        for j in range(len(name)):
            if age[j] == i+1:
                groupe += name[j]+" "
        print("Oldest groupe : " + groupe)
        break # quit the loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much David!  This is exactly what I was looking for.